# PHP/Javascript Web application invite friends

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Application Basics:

- Not a game
- Native / custom AnjuarlJS UI with PHP server-side code

I am loosing my mind here.  I have looked around for over a month for a solution and I am finally posting a question for help.

I have a web application that I am building for a friend.  This application is built with a JS(AngularJS) front end and a PHP backend.  I have been able to get logic in place for facebook login and allowing users to link a facebook account to their local account in my app.  The problem item here now is that we want to be able to allow users with facebook tied to their account to be able to invite their facebook friends to also us our website.  With this I want to be able to know the app-scoped ID for the users the invite is sent to to be able to automatically associate the users once the invited friend creates and account via the link.

- User A wants to invite User B to the application.

  - System stored ID of user B
- User B clicks on the link and creates an account on the application.

  - System checks User B's facebook id against list of stored invited ID's
  - If the system finds the user id the application should be able to now associate them as friends in our native database

Sure I could created a url as such : www.app.com/facebookInvite.php?fromUser=123
but this does not allow the situation where User A AND User C invite User B to the application.  Does ANYONE have a solution to this situation?  I have yet to find an answer that involves not being a game.

(I hope my question doesn't confuse anyone)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot know and record B's facebook id without B installing your app. This is changed when they introduced app-scoped ids.

I think the only thing you can do is that store the request with id-name pairs and when B installs the app, check the requests table if B's friends has installed the app and they sent a request to B.

For instance,

Lets say Michael (A here) has id 12, and Dwight has id 11.

```
inviter_id    inviter_name    invited_token    invited_name   
12            Michael         as1231e67dqd2e   Dwight
```

When Dwight installed the app, he should have Michael as a friend with id 12.  You can then check this table if Dwight is invited by his friends (Michael, Mose etc...) Since the names you stored in invited_name are not unique, this may give wrong results.

I hope I understood your question right :)

Comment: I was thinking about this and it seems like it would be a solution but using the send dialog you do not get a request id or anything.  I was also attempting to get a list of friends using the application (those who have authorized the app) and the list seems to continue to come up empty.

Comment: Why do you need the request id? Did you get user_friends permission in login dialog?